# xlwings Reports Quickstart throws errors

Tags: python, xlwings

Just trying the quickstart described here:
https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/reports.html#quickstart

I've copied the small code sample and created the template sheet as described. When I run report.py, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report.py", line 17, in <module>
    book = app.render_template(this_dir / 'mytemplate.xlsx',
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 699, in render_template
    return render_template(
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/pro/reports/main.py", line 439, in render_template
    wb = app.books.open(output)
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 4988, in open
    return Book(impl=self.impl.open(json=json))
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/pro/_xlremote.py", line 217, in open
    book = Book(api=json, books=self)
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/pro/_xlremote.py", line 268, in __init__
    if api["version"] != __version__:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report.py", line 20, in <module>
    book.to_pdf(this_dir / 'myreport.pdf')
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 764, in __exit__
    self.quit()
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 388, in quit
    return self.impl.quit()
  File "/home/james/dev/repos/eft/auto-reports/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/base_classes.py", line 50, in quit
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

This is essentially out of the box so I can't see that I've done anything wrong. I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Python is 3.8.10. I have the follwing dependencies:

```
numpy==1.23.4
pandas==1.5.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.5
six==1.16.0
xlwings==0.28.2
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, xlwings only worked on Windows or macOS with an actual installation of Microsoft Excel. More recently (in 2022) it added Linux support for [xlwings Server](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/remote_interpreter.html) and [xlwings File Reader](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/reader.html), but [xlwings Reports](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/reports.html) still has to be run in connection with Excel, i.e., runs on Windows and macOS only. While the [installation instructions](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html) mention this, I'll try to improve the docs to mark the requirements on the respective pages.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. So just to be clear, is it not possible to write to an Excel file without the involvemnet of a Windows/Mac machine? The report template function is exactly what I need but we generally use Linux servers here.

Comment: @jcstockdale That's correct as of today. It's all on the roadmap somewhere (although not on the immediate one)... so check back in a bit. ([GitHub issues](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues) would probably b a better place to do so...)